# Github - Is it posible to have private code in a public directory?

Tags: github, private-key

For my project, I need to send push notifications, but the private VapID key should not be visible for anyone on my public directory. Is it possible to have one file or one line not visible public, although it is a pubic GitHub directory?

Comment: Use .gitignore, rails encrypted secrets (if you have rails app), ansible-vault or other similar solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, No.

You might want to consider having that injected in for your release in your release/build pipeline via file or ENV variable.
You could also use a mechanism like Rails secrets where there is an ecrypted file in your repo to which only you hold the key and inject the key for deployment.